# How to let vim keep in insert mode when pressing Alt - h to move in insert mode?

Tags: vim

In order to edit fast in insert mode, we can use mapping keys to navigate in insert mode, for example

```
:inoremap <A-h> <Left>
```

with this mapping, user can press Alt + h in insert mode to let the cursor move left and then do insert, we don't need to exit edit mode, then move cursor. this will save some time for us, my question is when I use this mapping key, the cursor moves correctly, but vim switch to normal move after moving, it should keep in insert mode, I use vim 7.3 in Sun OS. I tried this in gvim 7.3 on windows, everything is good, so I wondered is there anything i lost?

Comment: If you insist on moving around in insert mode, why don't you simply use the arrows? Do you find `<A-h>` somehow more efficient than `<left>`?

Comment: Yes， with Alt-h, my hand don't need to move out the main area of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer here, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_meta-keys_that_break_out_of_Insert_mode, this will happened on Unix or Putty.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: if you think navigation in insert mode is speeding up your vim, you're using it wrong (i.e. like any other non-modal editor, when its biggest benefit is specifically modality).

That said, we can't say too much without you showing us your mapping. I suspect it is something like this:

```
inoremap <M-H> <Esc>h
```

Try changing to

```
inoremap <M-H> <C-O>h
```

Comment: sorry, add my key mappings, i think for some small changes, like word correction, it is fast to navigate in insert mode.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but you may find it sufficient to use forego the mapping and just use the right side of @Amadan's suggestion: typing `<C-o>h` will move the cursor to the left once and return to insert mode. `<C-o>` from insert mode will execute any single normal mode command and leave you in insert mode.

Comment: @zdd: All experienced vim users will agree that your intuition is not correct when you get used to The Vim Way. Navigating one character at a time is very inefficient when compared to `f`, `F`, `/`, `6j` and similar; and changing a word is much easier done with `xp`, `r`, `cw` and the like than in edit mode.